# Can't import simple Jar into Java WebApp on Tomcat8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8

I placed a `SHARED.jar` with a shared java class in it inside `CATALINA_HOME\lib`. I then modified the `catalina.properties` file so that the `shared.loader` value was set to `${catalina.home}\lib\SHARED.jar`. However, whenever I run an app (all of which are packaged as `.war`) referencing the class, it says `the requested resource isn't available.` It also says that the class I'm trying to reference should be located within the app itself. Why can't my webapps see the shared Jar and its classes?

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using and how are you referring to the resources in your java code?

Comment: The most recent version of tomcat8.  In the .java file I was calling it like a normal function and had put an import statement.  This worked fine for other jars (i.e. those used for logging), but not this custom made one.

Comment: You tried it without the ${catalina.home} prefix I assume? Have you verified you are calling the class correctly by getting it to work in a non-shared context?

Comment: I didn't try without the prefix, I'll give that a try.  I have verified that it works in a non-shared context.

Comment: Are you running under Windows or Linux?

Comment: I tried without the prefix, it still fails.  This is running under windows right now but the end target will be a Linux server.

Comment: Can you give me the output of $CATALINA_HOME and your full entry for catalina.properties? Also, is there another application running that has its own copy of the class you are trying to access in the shared.jar file?